# How to fetch the Promise object value from an array and use it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

I have two fetch requests inside the Promise. all function. I want to return a value like that

```
[
    {
        "name": "Yakup Kadri Karaosmanoğlu - Yaban.epub",
        "size": "217.5 KB",
        "date": "1/20/2021",
        "file": 'https://downloader.disk.yandex.ru/disk/ce4f0f5dce9c2b6475781cbb7df75fea0481e7154ba85ce458033babd45495bf/6161d2f8/Ojziu5Rkr3AlWOVIZvGJOuXWYQW2P8eZG0HUnfsnfkICk3YeJxoR5hpLAKFB6qGXoCQg004QfeWGolpZpYWxRg%3D%3D?uid=0&filename=Yakup%20Kadri%20Karaosmano%C4%9Flu%20-%20Yaban.epub&disposition=attachment&hash=I9yUHj%2BS67IaRxOANlGbhkKhx%2BMb83KCZa7A9q6PB7NuJBmsS3ntyZUZhtgmzgqmq/J6bpmRyOJonT3VoXnDag%3D%3D%3A/Meritokrasi/T%C3%BCrk%C3%A7e%20%5BePub%5D/Derecelendirilmi%C5%9F%20Kitaplar/Yakup%20Kadri%20Karaosmano%C4%9Flu%20-%20Yaban.epub&limit=0&content_type=application%2Fepub%2Bzip&owner_uid=1327282368&fsize=222724&hid=b47e4a1a2473bb99d2236114f54eeb94&media_type=book&tknv=v2'
    }
]
```

But my code turn me into an array like that

```
[
    {
        "name": "Yakup Kadri Karaosmanoğlu - Yaban.epub",
        "size": "217.5 KB",
        "date": "1/20/2021",
        "file": Promise{<fulfilled>'https://downloader.disk.yandex.ru/disk/ce4f0f5dce9c2b6475781cbb7df75fea0481e7154ba85ce458033babd45495bf/6161d2f8/Ojziu5Rkr3AlWOVIZvGJOuXWYQW2P8eZG0HUnfsnfkICk3YeJxoR5hpLAKFB6qGXoCQg004QfeWGolpZpYWxRg%3D%3D?uid=0&filename=Yakup%20Kadri%20Karaosmano%C4%9Flu%20-%20Yaban.epub&disposition=attachment&hash=I9yUHj%2BS67IaRxOANlGbhkKhx%2BMb83KCZa7A9q6PB7NuJBmsS3ntyZUZhtgmzgqmq/J6bpmRyOJonT3VoXnDag%3D%3D%3A/Meritokrasi/T%C3%BCrk%C3%A7e%20%5BePub%5D/Derecelendirilmi%C5%9F%20Kitaplar/Yakup%20Kadri%20Karaosmano%C4%9Flu%20-%20Yaban.epub&limit=0&content_type=application%2Fepub%2Bzip&owner_uid=1327282368&fsize=222724&hid=b47e4a1a2473bb99d2236114f54eeb94&media_type=book&tknv=v2'}
    }
]
```

My problem is I can't use the file link inside the promise. Here also I want to put the async call that I use to make some calls.

```
  fetch(`/books/${search}`)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then(async (d) => {
        const withChildren = d.map((e) => {
          return {
            name: e.name,
            size: bytes2Size(e.size),
            date: new Date(e.date).toLocaleDateString(),
            file: fetch(
              `https://cloud-api.yandex.net:443/v1/disk/public/resources/download?public_key=${encodeURI(
                'https://disk.yandex.ru/d/o9lNK0tpVCH7sQ'
              )}&path=${encodeURI(e.path)}`
            )
              .then((res) => res.json())
              .then(async (res) => res.href),
          };
        });
        await Promise.all(withChildren).then((res) => {
          setBooks(res);
          setIsLoaded(true);
        });
```

Is there any way to get rid of the Promise object and take only downloading link inside the array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reorder your promises to make requests first, then make the objects.

That makes sure you have all the data before returning the object, so you don't have any pending promises.

```js
fetch(`/books/${search}`)
  .then((res) => res.json())
  .then((d) => {
    Promise.all(d.map((e) => {
        return fetch(`https://cloud-api.yandex.net:443/v1/disk/public/resources/download?public_key=${encodeURI(
                'https://disk.yandex.ru/d/o9lNK0tpVCH7sQ'
              )}&path=${encodeURI(e.path)}`)
          .then(res => res.json())
          .then(res => {
              return {
                name: e.name,
                size: bytes2Size(e.size),
                date: new Date(e.date).toLocaleDateString(),
                file: res.href;
              })
          };
      }))
      .then(data => {
        setBooks(data);
        setIsLoaded(true);
      });
  });
```

Comment: setBooks(data) and with one semicolon error fixed then it worked :)

Comment: Thanks, I couldn't run it to debug, since the first request is relative.